# Specify arbitrary start and end times for cron job

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cron, scheduler, cronexpression

For Quartz Cron, is it possible at all to specify a cronexpression that corresponds to:

`Run every 6 minutes, starting from 9:12 AM until 5:37 PM.`

I attempted to write the cronexpression `0 12-37/6 9-17 ? * *` but this does only runs once an hour. I also [understand](http://www.cronmaker.com/) that the cronexpression `0 /6 9-17 ? * *` corresponds to `Run every 6 minutes between the hours of 9 AM and 5 PM`.

But is there any way to constrain the starting and ending minutes on that cronexpression? More generally, can I specify an arbitrary start and end time with the job in question running every `n` intervals of time?

Comment: 5 PM is hour 17 (not 14). `0 12-37/6 9-17 * * *` should do 9:12, 19, 24, 30, and 36 skip to 10:12 and run 5 times that hour. And keep on running 5 times an hour until 5:36 PM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with 3 cron strings:

```
0 12-59/6 9 * * *
0 /6 10-16 * * *
0 0-37/6 17 * * *
```

Give them all the same task to run.

Comment: oh dear please explain it. I have read it here but still confused http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

Comment: I would suggest you ask Stack Overflow specific questions. Or perhaps you should just Google for more Quartz tutorials or a good cron tutorial. The repeated event timing in Quartz can be done very much the same as with cron.

Comment: Thnx. Got answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051350/run-quartz-scheduler-job-with-specific-start-end-date-and-within-time-constrain/19058302?noredirect=1#19058302

Comment: @LeeMeador I am sorry but cronmaker.com says all these expressions are invalid. I tried to generate next run dates using Cronmaker. Can you explain?

Comment: @BhushanFirake cronmaker.com uses Quartz cron format. Evidently it does not allow using the dash and the slash together.