# Run Quartz Scheduler Job with specific start, end date and within time constraints

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz-Scheduler for repetitive tasks but I am facing a trouble. In my server side my user wants to specify some date range like **From** `2013-09-27` **with in** `09:00 AM - 12:00 PM` **to** `2013-09-30`

> Explanation:

Run a job from `2013-09-27` to `2013-09-30` but only between `09:00 AM - 12:00 PM`

I am facing trouble in writing a Cron expression for it, furthermore my user is non-technical so my user wants me to create Cron expression automatically from both time stamp values.

Please help me out. Let me know if there is another way.

I have seen many resources on Google but I still can't find nothing.

Links:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05

[Does cron expression in unix/linux allow specifying exact start and end dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704927/does-cron-expression-in-unix-linux-allow-specifying-exact-start-and-end-dates)

**Update**

I have  written one but it's not working

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Seconds | Minutes | Hours | DayOfMonth | Month | DayOfWeek | Year|
|         |         |       |            |       |           |     |
|   0     |    0    | 9-12  |   27-30    |   9   |     ?     | 2013|
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

trying to map `2013-09-27` to `2013-09-30` but only between `09:00 AM - 12:00 PM`

**Updated**
I have also tried it running with

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(NAME_TRIGGER_TASK_UPDATER, GROUP_TASK_TRIGGER)
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 9-12 19-22 10 ? *")).build();
```

but it doesn't give any error nor go into my execute method of my job

```
cronSchedule("0 0 9-12 ? * ?") throws invalid schedule exception.
```

The code below runs it without respecting the start and end date.

```
String startDateStr = "2013-09-27 00:00:00.0";
        String endDateStr = "2013-09-31 00:00:00.0";

        Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(startDateStr);
        Date endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(endDateStr);

        CronTrigger cronTrigger = newTrigger()
          .withIdentity("trigger1", "testJob")
          .startAt(startDate)
          .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 9-12 * * ?"))
          .endAt(endDate)
          .build();
```

Comment: You cron expression looks correct to me. Are other quartz triggers and jobs in your application executing as expected?

Comment: No just running this :-( Is there any difference for Quartz Scheduler Java ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is the error you get when you say it is not working?

You can try the following code (**Edit:** applies to Quartz 2.2). This approach does not specify the start/end dates and year in the cron expression, instead uses the Trigger methods to specify them.
(Note: I haven't tested it myself, let me know if it works for you)

**Edit:**
I had the chance to test this code, I ran the code below and kept changing the system clock and all triggers were successful between 9 am to 12 am from start to end date.

```
public class CronJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, SchedulerException {

        Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

        JobDetail job = newJob(TestJob.class)
            .withIdentity("cronJob", "testJob") 
            .build();

        String startDateStr = "2013-09-27 00:00:00.0";
        String endDateStr = "2013-09-31 00:00:00.0";

        Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(startDateStr);
        Date endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(endDateStr);

        CronTrigger cronTrigger = newTrigger()
          .withIdentity("trigger1", "testJob")
          .startAt(startDate)
          .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 9-12 * * ?").withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
          .endAt(endDate)
          .build();

        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, cronTrigger);
        scheduler.start();
    }    

    public static class TestJob implements Job {
        @Override
        public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
            System.out.println("this is a cron scheduled test job");
        }        
    }
}
```

If the above code does not work, try to replace the `cronSchedule("0 0 9-12 * * ?")` with `cronSchedule("0 0 9-12 ? * ?")`

Comment: i have try the code above and it work, the only matter is the trigger execute 20 second or later than that after the time it supposed to trigger. is it the quartz problem or external reason? i change my clock system to keep up with the date executed. can it be one of the reason

Comment: yes you need to ensure your system's clock is correctly set