# Task scheduling with Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz for scheduling parallel tasks, How can I get job running time in Quartz?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051350/run-quartz-scheduler-job-with-specific-start-end-date-and-within-time-constrain   and this http://www.mkyong.com/java/example-to-run-multiple-jobs-in-quartz/

Comment: What do you mean by job running time?  The execution schedule for future jobs or how long it takes to run one job?

Comment: how long it takes to run one job

Comment: Edit your question and add some details to better understand your problem..

Answer (score 1):

**JobExecutionContext** expose a some useful methods:

- [getJobRunTime](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html#getJobRunTime%28%29): returns the time only *after* the job has actually completed 
  (you may want to use a JobListener to call it when job finished the
  execution).
- [getFireTime](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html#getFireTime%28%29): get the actual time the job started, so you can the current Date to calculate the elapsed time (you can call this method even inside the Job itself).

**Note:** To know "how long it WILL takes to run one job" you have to implement on your own doing some simple math to get the % of completion. Quartz itself doesn't have such a feature.