# Is it possible to make a cron expression which runs between 9h30-11h30 and runs every 5 seconds in the interval?

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz's cron expression. I want to know if it's possible to setup a cron which start from 9h30 and end at 11h30 and run every 5s in the interval?

If it's not possible. Is there any other solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: minimum unit isnt 1 minute?

Comment: @YOU No, with Quartz scheduler the minimum unit is 1 second

Comment: may be you might need 3 tasks -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949449/specify-arbitrary-start-and-end-times-for-cron-job

Comment: @YOU that could be a solution. Thanks for the link.